# How to use dlib's shape_predictor in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, dlib

I'm trying to implement dlib's face landmark detection for an iOS application. 
On dlib's example they initialize a shape_predictor as such:

```
// And we also need a shape_predictor.  This is the tool that will predict face
// landmark positions given an image and face bounding box.  Here we are just
// loading the model from the shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat file you gave
// as a command line argument.
    shape_predictor sp;
    deserialize(argv[1]) >> sp;
```

I'm trying to do the same in Objective-C and have gotten this far:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks" ofType:@"dat"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Doing the following gives me an error of "Receiver type 'dlib::shape_predictor' is not an Objective-C class"

```
sp = [dlib::shape_predictor deserialize:myData];
```

Comment: The dlib library is a C++ library which I do not believe you can use directly in iOS since iOS uses Objective-C. I think you need to convert to Objective-c++. I have never tried this, but these links might help. [objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++](http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++) [Interoperating Between C++ and Objective-C](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/interoperating-between-c-and-objective-c/240165502)

Comment: [Facelandmarking with objective c and dlib](https://github.com/shaileshh/Mirror) small demo project for face detection using objective C n dlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have setup the dlib library correctly in the project (and included the source.cpp file), you need a .mm file (Objective-C++) in which you can do the following:

```
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/opencv.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
```

Then you can load the required dlib classes and use them with regular C++ syntax.
Here is an example:

```
dlib::frontal_face_detector detector = dlib::get_frontal_face_detector();
dlib::shape_predictor shapePredictor;

NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *landmarkdat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%s", mainBundle.bundlePath,"shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"];
dlib::deserialize(landmarkdat.UTF8String) >> shapePredictor;
```

Note: In my project I have added shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat as a bundle resource in Project->Target->Build Phrases->Copy bundle resources and checked the copy button.